# How to implement a "for" loop under an "if" condition in shell

Tags: shell, if-statement, for-loop

I have a requirement where in, I need to use a certain set of values, under a Nested if condition. I am trying to implement it using a for loop, but not able to put a correct syntax.

eg.

```
if [ "$i" -ge 353 ] && [ "$i" -lt 385 ]
then
   for((m=7001;m<7016;m++))
value=$m
done
fi
```

Is this a correct syntax?

Answer (score 5):

You need an extra `do` for the `for` loop. Formatting it makes it more clear:

```
if [ "$i" -ge 353 ] && [ "$i" -lt 385 ]
then
   for((m=7001;m<7016;m++))
   do
      value=$m
   done
fi
```

Note that all these `while`, `for`, etc need to be wrapped with `do` and `done`:

```
while #something
do
    things
done

for #condition
do
    things
done
```

> 'done' indicates that the code that used the value of $i has finished
>   and $i can take a new value.

And for the if:

```
if #condition; then
    things
fi
```

Comment: Hmm, I'm surprised bash allows `for((...))` without a space after "for"